# Using Python, Scan Text Fields in the database and Check a for Invalid Special Characters and Contents

Tags: python, special-characters, xml-entities

I want to Scan some database TextFields for Invalid Special Characters, the data from these textfields will be converted to XML and/or HTML page. 
 Moreover, I want to Check If an XML Self-Defining Entity like &#nnnn; is Valid.
What is the best way to do that in Python?
Does Python has any Library that can do that out of the box?

Comment: Welcome to SO. `Python` has ***a lot*** of decent libraries to accomplish exactly this. Please have some gooling before and come back with a specific code question afterwards.

Comment: Hint: look at standard library module `html`.